# How to use multidimensional array in object

Tags: php, arrays, object, post, multidimensional-array

how to use multidimensional array in an object type variable.

I need to pass two elements `disputer_id` and `disputer_ur_id‘ as you can see in`Q-dispute.php`file BUT when I try to use them through`call_ajax.php` I can't get my result even it other functions doesn't work.

**Q-dispute.php:**

```
var data = {};
data = ['<?php echo {$dispute_det[0]['disputer_id']}{$dispute_det[0]['disputer_ur_id']};?>','<?php echo $dispute[0]['order_id'];?>','<?php echo $_GET['via'];?>','<?php echo $_GET['d_token'];?>'];
$.post('/call_ajax.php',{holder: 'D-Accept',data: data},function(res){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(res);
    $('.dispute-closure').html(obj.msg);
```

**call_ajax.php:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE 
    `manage_order` 
SET 
    `release_flag`   = 'Y',
    `dispute_winner` = '{$_POST['data'][0][0]}'
    `disputer_ur_id` = '{$_POST['data'][0][1]}'
WHERE 
    `order_id` = '{$_POST['data'][1]}'";
```

Comment: why are you sending php code to your server?...

Comment: Though, I didn't get you fully. But still, for updating database we need it.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated source and tried doing a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the data you're sending actually looks like? As far as I can tell, `$_POST['data']` is not a multidimensional array. And the comment _"in an object type array"_ doesn't make much sense. You're just passing an ordinary array. This: `'<?php echo {$dispute_det[0]['disputer_id']}{$dispute_det[0]['disputer_ur_id']};?>'` will create one single string, not an array.

Comment: @Berto99 - They aren't sending php code, they are sending the values of those variables.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson actually, the code I published here is not the direct input from users, in fact data = ['<?php echo {$dispute_det[0]['disputer_id']}{$dispute_det[0]['disputer_ur_id']};?>','<?php echo $dispute[0]['order_id'];?> are result sets of server side queries. $dispute_det obtains data from the table including disputer_id but I can't pass values of more than one field. That's I posted my question here.

Comment: Those values are sent from the client to the server. Javascript lives in the browser and can be manipulated to be what ever someone wants (including SQL), no matter where the original values comes from. People can also post directly to your endpoint, so you are still wide open to SQL injections. You should basically never trust _any_ data that are sent to your backend. You also never addressed my second comment. The `data` value you're passing in is _not_ a multidimensional array. The id and ur_id are just concatenated into one single value.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for your response. I would like to discuss the matter for which I posted the question. Actually,

Comment: @MagnusEriksson data = ['<?php echo {$dispute_det[0]['disputer_id']}{$dispute_det[0]['disputer_ur_id']};?>',  As you can see 'data' is defined as an object and we are parsing different values through array. $dispute_det obtains result set of query. But, when I try to use it in the given way in order to pass 'disputer_id along with 'disputer_ur_id  and try to update in my database as you see in call_ajax.php I get error.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried  several ways to use  '<?php echo $dispute_det[0]['disputer_id'];?> and '<?php echo {$dispute_det[0]['disputer_ur_id'];?> separately in the same array but still get the same error at the time up update.

Comment: Since $dispute_det obtains the full result set, I need to configure out the way to pass values of both disputer_id and disputer_ur_id in the same array. I hope you understand me.

Comment: Pass in an object instead of an array: `{id: '<?= $dispute_det[0]['disputer_id'] ?>', ur_id: '<?= $dispute_det[0]['disputer_id'] ?>', order: '<?= ... ?>', via: '<?= ... ?>', token: '<?= ...?>'}`. Then in your PHP, you can fetch the data using: `$_POST['data']['id']`, `$_POST['data']['ur_id']` and so on. If that doesn't work, do a `var_dump($_POST);` on the PHP side to see what the actual structure of the data is.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson have a look our current code: 'var data = {};
data = ['<?php echo $dispute_det[0]['disputer_id'];?>','<?php echo $dispute[0]['order_id'];?>','<?php echo $_GET['via'];?>','<?php echo $_GET['d_token'];?>'];
$.post('/call_ajax.php',{holder: 'D-Accept',data: data},function(res){
    var obj = $.parseJSON(res);
    $('.dispute-closure').html(obj.msg);'